What causes Solve to occasionally hang on the same equation?
In the code displayed below, the line with Sols2 takes forever and doesn't solve the equation. However this exact same code worked 1 hour ago (the line containing Sols2 gave me the output {}).
Why is that so?
How can I always make it work?
As an important clarification: The line containing Sols2 is exactly the same as Sols1 with an extra unknown to be solved for (which doesn't appear in the equation). This line is then useless for all practical purposes, but I have a more complicated code where for some calls of Solve not all unknowns appear in the equations (I want to make this more complicated code work, this is why I reasoned on this minimal working example).
In[1]:=
$Assumptions = Flatten[{Element[α1, Reals], Element[β1, Reals], Element[ϕ1, Reals], Element[θ1, Reals], Element[α2, Reals], Element[β2, Reals], Element[ϕ2, Reals], Element[θ2, Reals]}]; 

Kgeneral[i_] = Array[k[i], {2, 2}]; 

Ageneral = Array[a, {2, 2}]; 

Bgeneral = Array[b, {2, 2}]; 

Sols1 = Solve[Table[Ageneral . Kgeneral[i] . Bgeneral == Transpose[Kgeneral[i]], {i, 1, 4}], Flatten[Table[{a[i, j], b[i, j]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]]]
(* {} *)

Sols2 = Solve[Table[Ageneral . Kgeneral[i] . Bgeneral == Transpose[Kgeneral[i]], {i, 1, 4}], Flatten[{Table[{a[i, j], b[i, j]}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], α1}]]
(* $Aborted *)


Not really an answer as to why, but if you remove the assumption that α1 is real then Sols2 produces the same empty solution as Sols1.

@ydd Thank you. You are right (and this is also helpful for me that you noticed this, so thanks!).
